# How to implement a sklearn transformer with sklearn.base.SimpleImputer but returns a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, imputation

I want to implement a customer transformer with sklearn imputer, e.g., sklearn.base.SimpleImputer.

The output should be a dataframe,

I have the following code, but not sure if this is correct

```
class DFSimpleImputer(TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.imp = SimpleImputer(*args, **kwargs)

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    self.imp.fit(X)
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    # assumes X is a DataFrame
    Ximp = self.imp.transform(X)
    Xfilled = pd.DataFrame(Ximp, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)
    return Xfilled
```

Comment: Why do you need to have this in your imputer? If you need to have it as a dataframe, you can just as well do pd.DataFrame(imp_mean.transform(X)) ?

Comment: Any custom transformer should probably also inherit from `BaseEstimator`.

Comment: @rvf, thanks for the answer, transformerMixin is sufficient for transformer (fit, transform and fit_transform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code above works and returns a dataframe. The question that you need to ask is why you need a DataFrame when build transformers (yes, it adds label for easy reading). Maybe nparray is better since you may encounter sparse matrix and DataFrame will eat up all your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

My code above actually works per test, it fits the datasets, then transform. The end results are converted into a DataFrame. The drawback though is that the default return nparray from SimpleImputer would be better than DataFrame if we end up with a sparse matrix. So transforming nparray into dataframe is good for research purpose, but in production I might switch back to nparray